# Is there a way to edit a single character in an array element?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I have the following array in which element 9 consists of the following: `"abcdef"`.

So if I do `echo "{array[9]}"` I get `"abcdef"`.

I want to change a character in that position in the array, e.g. the d to h so I could just do `array[9]="abchef"`

But that would only work if the content is "abcdef". My goal is to find a way, if possible, to change a character avoiding that way, so that I can do it in any array. For example, to change the fourth character to an "h" as I have done.

To edit a 6-character string and change the fourth would do:

```
part1=$(string:1:3)
part2=$(string:5:6)
newstring+=$part1$char$part2
```

Assuming the character I want to change is stored in the variable char.

Comment: Let's take arrays out of the equation. Do you know how to change the fourth character of a string variable?

Comment: I think so although I'm not 100% sure because of your question, is there any mistake in my code?

Comment: If you had a variable `$string` with unknown contents, how would you change its fourth character to `h`? Can you [edit] your question and show what that would look like?

Comment: What I'm getting it is you should break the problem down: replacing the fourth character of a string is one problem; updating an array is another. It would be good to focus your question on one of those two sub-problems.

Comment: I have already edited the question, I don't know if this is the correct solution.

Comment: No, it's not. Use curly braces (`{}`) instead of parentheses. And then replace `string` by `array[9]` and you'll be done. In one line: `array[9]="${array[9]:0:3}h${array[9]:4}"`.